# Probability over a ring

Tags: probability

I face a calculation that looks simple but I can't find the correct solution.
Let's say I make $k$ uniform random selections over a ring of size $q$, I want to know the probability of having those $k$ values in an interval of size $q/m$.
For example, if $m=4$, I want to know the probability of having k samples in an interval of size $q/4$. If I choose a specific interval, the probability is obviously $1/4^k$. But I want to know the probability for the sampling to happen in any interval of that size. I can't just multiply by $q$, because there are overlaps, and expanding $P(A_1\cup A_2...\cup A_q)$ is quite cumbersome. It is also bigger than $1/4^{k-1}$ because you have 4 separate intervals + overlapping intervals. I feel there is a symmetry trick to catch here, or something obvious,since all intervals of size 1 are the same, but I can't quite grasp it yet. I just don't want to lose to much time on it, so if anyone has a better idea, and can be my chatgpt, I take it.
thanks in advance.

Edit: I thought I had it.

Edit:Edit:I didn't

Comment: "be my chatgpt" , I think it is better for you if noone is "your chatgpt".

Comment: @Peter yes I realise it was pretty bad at mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I will assume that $m$ is a divisor of $q$. Also, I will assume that $m\ge 2$.

The answer is
$$
\boxed{
q\left(\frac1{m^k}-\left(\frac1m-\frac1q\right)^k\right).
}
$$

For each $i\in \{1,\dots,q\}$, let $E_i$ be the event that the $i^\text{th}$ item is one of the chosen items, *and* that all of the items lie in the interval of length $q/m$ whose clockwise endpoint is the $i^\text{th}$ item. You need to check three things.

- In order for all of the items to lie in an interval of $q/m$ items, at least one of the events $E_1,\dots,E_q$ must occur.
- The events $E_1,\dots,E_q$ are mutually exclusive. Therefore, to compute the probability that at least one of them occurs, you can just do $q\cdot P(E_1)$.
- $P(E_1)=(1/m)^k-\left(1/m-1/q\right)^k$. Note that $(1/m)^k$ is the probability that all of the items lie in the interval of length $q/m$ starting at the first item. However, since $E_1$ requires the first item to be one of the chosen items, we need to subtract the probability that all of the items lie in the smaller interval with only $(q/m-1)$ items, where the first item is omitted. That is, we subtract $(1/m-1/q)^k$.

Note that in the limit as $q\to\infty$ with $k,m$ fixed, the probability approaches $k(1/m)^{k-1}$. Indeed, this is the correct answer for the continuous version of the problem, where each of the $k$ random points can have any real number between $0$ and $2\pi$ for its angle.

Comment: That's funny because I tried to center it around the first value, giving an interval of + or -q/m for the second, after imposing the first value, (so 2q/m possibilities) which then depending on the second value would impact where the third value could go etc... I didn't think at restricting the first one to be in a q/m interval, silly me. Thanks

Comment: So for the first point, among the $k$ items I select for each $E_i$, there is one "smallest" item which sets the interval $I_{x_i}$ ,hence the $(1/m)^{k-1}$ because the $x_i$ sets which element is the "smallest".For example $E_2$ sets the smallest element of the interval to be $x_2$, and all others have to be in $I_x2$.But I am a bit confused about the point 2, first there is a $(1-(1-1/q)^{k-1})$ probability that another $E_i$ has the same interval than another $E_j$, and it seems to me that since $I_3 \cap I_4 = {4,5,6}$ the two event are not disjoints.I don't really understand the $E_i$.

Comment: I'm not very confident in the formula, and another reason for that is that I want to use it for intervals bigger than q/2 for example 0.999q. If I extend that formula to such cases, the probability can be bigger than 1.

Comment: I now feel confused about my own comment. I found a way to reason more or less like you. But I see the increase with k as a problem. That being said, if I take a small example with $k=2$ it's meaningless to search for 1/m greater than 1/2 because we are on a ring and so the probability is necessarily 1, there will always be an interval greater than q/2 containing 2 values. With k=3 though it seems to me it becomes possible. Ok so I need to think about it clearly, but you gave me good hints.

Comment: @BenoitAvril My answer is correct now.

Comment: will look into it, but I still doubt it, I made a calculation that pretty much looks like it, but those were only the two first terms and there were additional terms. It's early where I am, I just woke up, I will edit my question and show the reasoning

Comment: I still don't see why they are mutually exclusive. if all values fall in 2..q/m , you are both in 1...q/m and 2..q/m+1 and so on.

Comment: At least the formula works for m=2 and q = 4, so I will think about it, thank you.

Comment: Ok so let's say m is not an integer, we have q = 999 and  1/m= 665/999, then the function q(1/m^x-(1/m-1/q)^x) is bigger than 1 as soon as x is bigger than 1 and comes under 1 at about 5. It's not a probability. Let's say it remains a probability and if the formula is above 1 the probability is 1. Then you can find 3 values that won't fit in an interval of size 665, while the formula says the probability for any sample to lie in is (above) 1. For example, if x = 3, there is no interval of size 665 that will contain 333,666,999, so the probability can not be 1.